# SwiftUI: Doesn't pass data from selected list item into detail view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been trying to show selected item's detail view but can't seem to get it working. When trying to get the name of the item into the detail view by `diaries.name` I get an error `Value of type '[DiaryItem]' has no member 'name'`

```
ForEach(diaries.items) {item in
NavigationLink(destination: DiaryDetailView(diaries: diaries)) {
     HStack {
     VStack(alignment: .leading) {
     Text(item.name)
    .font(.headline)
    }
               Spacer()
                        
  } //: HSTACK
 }//: FOR
}
```

And here is the detail view

```
struct DiaryDetailView: View {
    
    let diaries: Diaries
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(diary.name)
        }
}
}
struct DiaryDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DiaryDetailView(diaries: Diaries())
    }
}
```

And my class where it saves the form information

```
class Diaries: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [DiaryItem]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([DiaryItem].self, from: savedItems) {
                items = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }

        items = []
    }
}
```

```
struct DiaryItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let fishName: String
    let info: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably wanted something like this:

```
ForEach(diaries.items) {item in
NavigationLink(destination: DiaryDetailView(diary: item)) { // <-- here
     HStack {
     VStack(alignment: .leading) {
     Text(item.name)
    .font(.headline)
    }
               Spacer()
                        
  } //: HSTACK
 }//: FOR
}

struct DiaryDetailView: View {
    let diary: DiaryItem  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(diary.name)
        }
}
}
```

and

```
struct DiaryDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DiaryDetailView(diary: DiaryItem(name: "name1", fishName: "fish1", info: "info1"))
    }
}
```